# Not able to launch any application in GCP, billing not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka

For practicing Kafka, I have created a free GCP account.

I have given my account information and money is deducted from my credit card.
When I try to launch my Kafka application page it is again redirected to account information page and it is asking me for payment. I have made the payment for almost 10 times. Kafka application is never launched.
The same happens when I try to link a billing account to my project or perform anything from the GCP console.

I don't understand what went wrong. Can someone please guide me as I am new to GCP as well.

Comment: Watch a few of these Google Cloud videos on billing. https://www.jhanley.com/videolabs/Google-Cloud-Billing/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be a support request to Google.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to [change your payment method](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#available_payment_methods) (they vary depending on the country you live in) and of that doesn't help (or you are not able for some reason) I recommend contacting [Google Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/?visit_id=637551245730996661-3605218127&rd=1#how_to_contact_support) - in case of any billing issues it's free of charge.

You can contact [GCP Billing Support via the chat](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/chat) and explain what's the issue.

Comment: Appreciate your inputs.I tried with both Credit and Debit card,it's the same result.One of my colleague also tried creating GCP account,he has the same issue as i have. I tried reaching out to GCP Billing support yesterday but i get you are not an administrator on any billing account(Sorry to miss this in the topic yesterday).Please suggest me any other ways to reach out to GCP support.

Comment: Just contact them and explain what's happening and they will be able to help you more than I do.